# java: how to call a method on arraylist without knowing the type of object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an intersect method that takes two ArrayLists that hold the same type of object and returns a list of objects that are in both lists.

```
public static ArrayList<TimeSlot> intersectTS(ArrayList<TimeSlot> List1, ArrayList<TimeSlot> List2)
{
    ArrayList<TimeSlot> intersection = new ArrayList<TimeSlot>();
    for(TimeSlot TS1 : List1)
    {
        for(TimeSlot TS2 : List2)
        {
            if(TimeSlot.Equals(TS2,TS1))
            {
                intersection.add(TS2);
            }
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

Right now it can only take TimeSlot objects and I have to create an almost identical method for every other type of object that I want to use this method on.

Is there a way to do this in one method?

Thanks

Comment: Use generics ? `public static ArrayList<T> intersectTS(List<T> list1, List<T> list2)`

Comment: Assuming that you meant `equals`, rather than some special `Equals` method from the `TimeSlot` class, then svasa's comment is the correct answer.

Comment: Please adhere to the Java naming conventions, and it would be interesting to see the code for `TimeSlot.Equals`. Why not the normal `equals` method, or does it do something different?

Comment: @svasa's answer left out the `<T>` before the `ArrayList<T>` but is otherwise correct.

Comment: Yeah I guess the Equals thing is a little weird.  I picked up java to work on a project, but I don't know much about the inner workings.  I'm only good with Python.  Is "equals" a special method?

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1 - [Generics](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm)

```
public static <T extends TimeSlot> ArrayList<T> intersectTS(ArrayList<T> List1, ArrayList<T> List2)
{
    ArrayList<T> intersection = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(T TS1 : List1)
    {
        for(T TS2 : List2)
        {
            if(TimeSlot.Equals(TS2,TS1))
            {
                intersection.add(TS2);
            }
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

Now this assumes that the generic object you pass in has the method `Equals(T, T)`, and to tell the compile you're going to only pass in objects that meet that condition, you can use `<T extend TimeSlot>` where `TimeSlot` is an interface.

---

### Approach 2 - [Inheritance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm)

```
public static ArrayList<ParentObject> intersectTS(ArrayList<ParentObject> List1, ArrayList<ParentObject> List2)
{
    ArrayList<ParentObject> intersection = new ArrayList<ParentObject>();
    for(ParentObject TS1 : List1)
    {
        for(ParentObject TS2 : List2)
        {
            if(ParentObject.Equals(TS2,TS1))
            {
                intersection.add(TS2);
            }
        }
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

This approach assumes that you have an object, `ParentObject` that has a method `Equals(ParentObject, ParentObject)` and your `TimeSlot` class extends `ParentObject`.

---

If you wan't more guidance on either method let me know and I will expand on the answer.